# How can I see what attributes are signed inside a PKCS 7 file?

Tags: openssl, sign, pkcs#7

I have a [PKCS 7](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_7) file, which contains signed data. It successfully verifies:

```
openssl smime -verify -in data.p7s -CAfile root-certificate.pem
```

Output:

```
Verification successful
Signed data
```

But when I extract the signed part, I do not see that it is actually the same as what was signed. I mean the following steps:

```
openssl asn1parse -in data.p7s
```

Output:

```
...
   35:d=4  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :pkcs7-data
   46:d=4  hl=2 l=inf  cons: cont [ 0 ]
   48:d=5  hl=2 l=inf  cons: OCTET STRING
   50:d=6  hl=2 l=   5 prim: OCTET STRING      :(my data is here in plaintext)
...
(then the signed block starts:)
 2861:d=6  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :rsaEncryption
 2872:d=6  hl=2 l=   0 prim: NULL
 2874:d=5  hl=4 l= 256 prim: OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]:<signed data is here>
```

I cut the `[HEX DUMP]` with the signed data:

```
dd if=data.p7s of=signed-part.bin bs=1 skip=2878 count=256
```

Decrypt it with the corresponding public key:

```
openssl rsautl -verify -in signed-part.bin -pubin -inkey root-public-key.pem -out verified-data.bin
```

And look inside the result:

```
openssl asn1parse -inform der -in verified-data.bin
```

Output:

```
 0:d=0  hl=2 l=  33 cons: SEQUENCE
 2:d=1  hl=2 l=   9 cons: SEQUENCE
 4:d=2  hl=2 l=   5 prim: OBJECT            :sha1
11:d=2  hl=2 l=   0 prim: NULL
13:d=1  hl=2 l=  20 prim: OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]:<hash here>
```

This `[HEX DUMP]` is *not* the [SHA-1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1) sum of my original data.

I do not understand why the hash is different. Obviously, it's a hash of something different than my original data. Does the hash also cover any "Authenticated attributes"? If yes, how to see what exactly attributes have been hashed and signed?

Comment: Why did you add 4 to 2874 ?

Comment: @user1511417 because 4 bytes are used by the header (`hl=4`), the data starts after it.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using a different sample:

OpenSSL `asn1parse` does not help much identifying the authenticated attributes. You can use OpenSSL `cms`:

```
openssl cms -in data.p7s -noout -cmsout -print
```

Look for `signedAttrs` ("signed attributes" is how the "authenticated attributes" are now called, in CMS terminology)

It will look like this:

```
    ...
    signerInfos:
        ...
        signedAttrs:
            object: contentType (1.2.840.113549.1.9.3)
            value.set:
              OBJECT:pkcs7-data (1.2.840.113549.1.7.1)
            object: signingTime (1.2.840.113549.1.9.5)
            ...
```

Now go back to `asn1parse` output, and find the corresponding part, which may look like:

```
 ...
 1343:d=5  hl=3 l= 216 cons:      cont [ 0 ]
 1346:d=6  hl=2 l=  24 cons:       SEQUENCE
 1348:d=7  hl=2 l=   9 prim:        OBJECT            :contentType
 1359:d=7  hl=2 l=  11 cons:        SET
 1361:d=8  hl=2 l=   9 prim:         OBJECT            :pkcs7-data
 1372:d=6  hl=2 l=  28 cons:       SEQUENCE
 1374:d=7  hl=2 l=   9 prim:        OBJECT            :signingTime
 ...
```

(for this nice indentation, add the `-i` option)

Now, extract (`dd ...`) the data, including the DER context tag header, i.e., offset 1343, length 219, in this case. Then replace the `0xa0` byte at the beginning by `0x31`. Why you have to do it, is described in *[DER encoding - How to convert implicit tag to explicit tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3638495/der-encoding-how-to-convert-implicit-tag-to-explicit-tag)*, or [RFC5652, section 5.4](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5652#section-5.4)

The SHA-1 hash of this data should now match.

Comment: Dear @mykhal , I have a question about PKCS7. Is P7 used for Typical messages (Unencrypted messages)? I mean Is it true that all messages in P7 format are encrypted? Does encryption is mandatory in this format?

Comment: The part "replace the `0xa0` byte at the beginning by `0x31`" saved my day. Thank you.

Comment: @mykhal,  why the length is 219 but 216? the length seems 216 from this line "1343:d=5  hl=3 l= 216"

Comment: My PDF is readable and verifies correctly in PDFXchange, but I get this error when using the `cms` on the extracted *.pkcs7 file `commandError reading SMIME Content Info
40374EE57B7F0000:error:068000D1:asn1 encoding routines:SMIME_read_ASN1_ex:no content type:../crypto/asn1/asn_mime.c:415:`

Comment: Wasted 2 days without that a0->31 trick - man, you're legend!