# Verification of pdf integrity fail

Tags: security, pdf, pkcs#7

I'm trying to verify via bash commands the integrity of a pdf file.

Using dd I extracted the signedContent and the pkcs7 detached object of the pdf.

Then I decoded the pkcs via

```
xxd -r -p pkcs7_extracted > pkcs7_extracted.bin

openssl asn1parse -inform DER <pkcs7_extracted.bin >pkcs7_extracted_decoded
```

from the decoded pkcs7 I got some useful information as

```
 0:d=0  hl=4 l=5498 cons: SEQUENCE         
 4:d=1  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :pkcs7-signedData
 15:d=1  hl=4 l=5483 cons: cont [ 0 ]        
 19:d=2  hl=4 l=5479 cons: SEQUENCE          
 23:d=3  hl=2 l=   1 prim: INTEGER           :01
 26:d=3  hl=2 l=  15 cons: SET               
 28:d=4  hl=2 l=  13 cons: SEQUENCE          
 30:d=5  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :sha256
 41:d=5  hl=2 l=   0 prim: NULL              
 43:d=3  hl=2 l=  11 cons: SEQUENCE          
 ...
 5154:d=7  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :contentType
 5165:d=7  hl=2 l=  11 cons: SET               
 5167:d=8  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :pkcs7-data
 5178:d=6  hl=2 l=  47 cons: SEQUENCE          
 5180:d=7  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :messageDigest
 5191:d=7  hl=2 l=  34 cons: SET               
 5193:d=8  hl=2 l=  32 prim: OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]:18B399D208A08815DDF23C93B1B63B13757A6AA24B1932569D7A69D0DB3A34C2
 5227:d=5  hl=2 l=  13 cons: SEQUENCE          
 5229:d=6  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :sha256WithRSAEncryption
 5240:d=6  hl=2 l=   0 prim: NULL              
 5242:d=5  hl=4 l= 256 prim: OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]: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
 5502:d=0  hl=2 l=   0 prim: EOC
```

in particular I notice that the messageDigest field is equal to the calculated digest of the signedContent obtained using the ByteRange.

I've so extracted the encrypted hash, decrypted it with my publickey and decoded again with asn1 command.

```
dd if=pkcs7_extracted.bin of=extracted.sign.bin bs=1 skip=$[ 5242 + 4 ] count=256

#decrypt

openssl rsautl -verify -pubin -inkey publickey.pem < extracted.sign.bin > verified.bin

#decode of result
openssl asn1parse -inform der -in verified.bin
```

the result is this object

```
0:d=0  hl=2 l=  49 cons: SEQUENCE          
2:d=1  hl=2 l=  13 cons: SEQUENCE          
4:d=2  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :sha256
15:d=2  hl=2 l=   0 prim: NULL              
17:d=1  hl=2 l=  32 prim: OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]:EBAA31519CD0CCA793FEC34AA6BDD8DFA5E4D5F63BA4711F6C8ECE5D20FEF393
```

I'm pretty sure decryption worked since the object is correctly decoded and as I expected contains a sha256 object but as you can see the digest value is **different**...

Am I looking in the wrong place? I've no more idea how to verify the integrity.

In addition Acrobat of course validate the integrity of the document for this signature.

thanks in advance!

Comment: Please be aware that in a SignedData object there are multiple hash values to consider which generally are not equal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please be aware that in a `SignedData` object there are multiple hash values to consider which generally are not equal.

Have a look at the definition of the Cryptographic Message Syntax (CMS) objects in [RFC 3852](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3852).

([RFC 3852](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3852) is the RFC referenced from the current PDF specification ISO 32000-1; thus, even though it is *obsoleted by* [RFC 5652](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5652), changes in the newer RFC might not apply in this context.)

```
  SignedData ::= SEQUENCE {
    version CMSVersion,
    digestAlgorithms DigestAlgorithmIdentifiers,
    encapContentInfo EncapsulatedContentInfo,
    certificates [0] IMPLICIT CertificateSet OPTIONAL,
    crls [1] IMPLICIT RevocationInfoChoices OPTIONAL,
    signerInfos SignerInfos }

...

  SignerInfo ::= SEQUENCE {
    version CMSVersion,
    sid SignerIdentifier,
    digestAlgorithm DigestAlgorithmIdentifier,
    signedAttrs [0] IMPLICIT SignedAttributes OPTIONAL,
    signatureAlgorithm SignatureAlgorithmIdentifier,
    signature SignatureValue,
    unsignedAttrs [1] IMPLICIT UnsignedAttributes OPTIONAL }

...

  SignedAttributes ::= SET SIZE (1..MAX) OF Attribute

...

  signedAttrs is a collection of attributes that are signed.  The
  field is optional, but it MUST be present if the content type of
  the EncapsulatedContentInfo value being signed is not id-data.
  SignedAttributes MUST be DER encoded, even if the rest of the
  structure is BER encoded.  Useful attribute types, such as signing
  time, are defined in Section 11.  If the field is present, it MUST
  contain, at a minimum, the following two attributes:

     A content-type attribute having as its value the content type
     of the EncapsulatedContentInfo value being signed.  Section
     11.1 defines the content-type attribute.  However, the
     content-type attribute MUST NOT be used as part of a
     countersignature unsigned attribute as defined in section 11.4.

     A message-digest attribute, having as its value the message
     digest of the content.  Section 11.2 defines the message-digest
     attribute.

...

  The result of the message digest calculation process depends on
  whether the signedAttrs field is present.  When the field is absent,
  the result is just the message digest of the content as described
  above.  When the field is present, however, the result is the message
  digest of the complete DER encoding of the SignedAttrs value
  contained in the signedAttrs field.  Since the SignedAttrs value,
  when present, must contain the content-type and the message-digest
  attributes, those values are indirectly included in the result.
```

Thus, your observation

> that the messageDigest field is equal to the calculated digest of the signedContent obtained using the ByteRange.

```
 5178:d=6  hl=2 l=  47 cons: SEQUENCE          
 5180:d=7  hl=2 l=   9 prim: OBJECT            :messageDigest
 5191:d=7  hl=2 l=  34 cons: SET               
 5193:d=8  hl=2 l=  32 prim: OCTET STRING      [HEX DUMP]:18B399D208A08815DDF23C93B1B63B13757A6AA24B1932569D7A69D0DB3A34C2
```

indicates that the correct data is signed because the *message-digest attribute* shall have *as its value the message digest of the content*.

But as you can also read here, the data signed by the actual inner *signature* bytes (which you decrypted) is *not this message digest of the content* but instead the *collection of attributes signedAttrs*!

**Thus, you must not verify those *signature* bytes against the *content* hash but against the *signed attributes* hash as described in the RFC.**

PS: The OP meanwhile found [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24581628/1729265) on the topic of CMS signed data verification which additionally illustrates how one can more graphically identify which attributes are signed and which are not.

PPS: The OP verifies by *decrypting* the signature bytes, extracting the contained hash, and comparing it with the actual one. This is ok for signatures based on RSA. Signatures based on DSA or ECDSA cannot be decrypted, though, so the hash value cannot be extracted. Special verification routines must be used for their verification.

PPPS: There are different styles of integrated PDF signatures. While the style (PKCS7/CAdES detached) used here is the most common and recommended one, in a generic solution one has to check beforehand and verify accordingly.

Comment: thanks a lot! to complete the answer i'd link to [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24567623/how-to-see-what-attributes-are-signed-inside-pkcs7) in order to understand which are the signed attributes.